# ActionMode action for multiple checkboxes

Tags: android

For my ListView I'm using

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new ModeCallback());

private class ModeCallback implements ListView.MultiChoiceModeListener {
```

I can long press on an item and get the action buttons that I want to work with. I want to change this to Checkbox item click. Do I have to use a different choice mode as modal seems to  work only for long press?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for the below link it can solve your problem.....

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listadvanced_interactive

Answer (score 1):

The Downloads app in Ice Cream Sandwich starts ActionMode from a Checkbox. This is the class that sets up ActionMode. [DownloadsList](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_providers_DownloadProvider/blob/ics/ui/src/com/android/providers/downloads/ui/DownloadList.java) And this class used to start it from the Checkbox. [DownloadItem](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_providers_DownloadProvider/blob/ics/ui/src/com/android/providers/downloads/ui/DownloadItem.java) So, everything you need is there.